# I am not able to reset my password on Stack Exchange

Tags: bug

I've forgotten my password and never receive a password resetting link with the associated email ACCOUNT and anything,I don't want to log in via face-book what should I do to reset my login?I've seen my Junk and everything but did not find the mail?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, it looks like you logged in via Facebook 20 minutes ago (some time before posting this) but anyway. While we site mods can see how you log in, we can't see what's wrong with the central login server (openid.stackexchange.com). We aren't in a position to help debug email problems other than to say "it looks like it sent the message, check it isn't being binned".

So for service level issues like this, I'd recommend talking to SE directly via the [contact page](https://askubuntu.com/contact).